# How to send back data from a JSON request

Tags: c#, vb.net, web-services, json

I have an existing WSDL which returns information to remote devices using SOAP. However, I'm writing a new app with Android which doesn't support SOAP so I can't use the existing WSDL and have had to code a new app which looks for a querystring from the Android app and returns the data in a JSON packet. I've coded the module which receives the data okay but I'm unsure how to send the data back in JSON format, does anyone have any examples in VB.Net or C# which shows me how to return the data to the JSON requestor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll be pleased to know .NET makes this really simple, using the [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx). Here is some code, pulled from a HTTP Handler. `MyDataType` is the name of your serializable class.

```
context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
MyDataType someObject = new MyDataType();
DataContractJsonSerializer ser = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(MyDataType));
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    ser.WriteObject(ms, data);
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
    string json = sr.ReadToEnd();
    Trace("Returning JSON:\n" + json + "\n");
    context.Response.Write(json);
}
```

[This is](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/218001.aspx) the main blog post I used when I had to do this.

Comment: That's really helpful, thanks. As I mentioned I haven't used Json before and the code in your blog was really helpful. Am I right in thinking that I can call my module from my Android app like 'http://myweb.com.default.ascx?memid=333' and then process the querystring in pageload and return the resulting data using code similar to above?

Comment: You could use an ascx, but I would generally use a HTTP handler (an ASMX file) for this sort of thing, as they are a lot more lightweight. You can access the query string using context.Request.Params("memid"), and then use the code above to write the output to your client.